# Capacitor registration event not fired

Tags: android, vue.js, firebase-cloud-messaging, capacitor

I have following problem: In my app i try to get the notification token with

```
  if (this.isNative) {
        PushNotifications.addListener(
          'pushNotificationReceived',
          (notification) => {
            this.$store.commit('SET_NOTIFICATION', {
              show: true,
              text: notification.body,
            })
          }
        )
        PushNotifications.addListener('registration', (token) => {
          DataStore.query(User, this.userData.username).then((res) => {
            alert(res.id)
            DataStore.save(
              User.copyOf(res, (updated) => {
                updated.pushToken = token.value
              })
            )
          })
        })
        await PushNotifications.requestPermissions()
        await PushNotifications.register()
    }
```

The event `PushNotifications.addListener("registration")` does not get fired for some reason... When i try it in the emulator with Pixel 3 it actually works fine, but on my own phone it does not

Are there some differences i should know between emulator and my physical phone?

Comment: Try the registration error event just in case it’s firing with more information

Comment: @jcesarmobile i tried. i wrapped everything inside `try / catch` and did `alert(err)` but nothing happends. no error and no event. inside the android pixel 3 emulator it works fine for some reason